# Uploaded tmp file not found in query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm fairly new to php and CakePHP, and I'm trying to execute the following code after uploading a text file (2kb):

```
$filefullname = $this->request->data['File']['file']['tmp_name'];
debug($filefullname);
move_uploaded_file($filefullname, WWW_ROOT.'tmp.txt');
$query = 'LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY INFILE "'.WWW_ROOT.'tmp.txt'.'" INTO TABLE agencies FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" LINES TERMINATED BY "\r" IGNORE 1 LINES';
debug($query);
$this->Agency->query($query);
```

Though the file can be found, I get the following output:

```
'C:\Windows\Temp\phpB413.tmp'
'LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY INFILE "C:\Data\myphpapplication\app\webroot\tmp.txt" INTO TABLE agencies FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" LINES TERMINATED BY "\r" IGNORE 1 LINES'
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 29 File 'C:\Data\myphpapplication\app\webroot\tmp.txt' not found (Errcode: 13)
SQL Query: LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY INFILE "C:\Data\myphpapplication\app\webroot\tmp.txt" INTO TABLE agencies FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" LINES TERMINATED BY "\r" IGNORE 1 LINES
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure. but is it case sensitive for the driver C to be capital in the query??

Comment: I've edited the question to contain the updated code. I've also tried to replace all `\` by `\\` with no luck.

Comment: is you file utf8. or have you tried to make it local inside db directory ? and do you have permission to read it??

Comment: On windows the path name must use forward slashes with `LOAD DATA ..`. (or double backslashes). Whether this is the cause of your problem I don' t know, but it might suggest why it can't find the file.

Comment: and as long as it's in the webroot just try ./tmp.txt , let me know if it worked or not?

Comment: Are you attempting to upload the contents of the `.txt` into the database? If so, you haven't designated what fields get what values. Also, I think the `ENCLOSED BY """"` block is an issue. I think it should be more like `ENCLOSED BY '\"'` to escape the quotes, unless you're trying to say there aren't any quotes enclosing the lines?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I've tried using `move_uploaded_file($filefullname, '/tmp.txt');`, which results in the creation of `c:\tmp.txt`. Using `...INFILE "/tmp.txt" INTO...` results in ` General error: 29 File 'C:\tmp.txt' not found (Errcode: 13)`. Also, apparently I have permission to write it (tmp.txt gets created) so reading shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: @gtr1971 I've just copy pasted this query from somewhere, I'll fix any problems with that when I can actually use the file in the query.

Comment: Have you tried @Ross suggestion? I have never had any luck using the `/` when accessing local filesystem. Always used \

Comment: I've tried that as well, with no luck.

Comment: @i meant using it in your query not moving it like that. Keep www root in moving and use ./ in sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the file is there, but MySQL doesn't allow you to read files from that location. MySQL is fairly restrictive from where it reads LOAD DATA ... INFILE, with good reasons. You may need to move your file first to a path that MySQL can read from, or change the settings for your MySQL server.

From the MySQL 5.1 manual:

> Note that, in the non-LOCAL case, these rules mean that a file named
>   as ./myfile.txt is read from the server's data directory, whereas the
>   file named as myfile.txt is read from the database directory of the
>   default database. [...]

And:

> Windows path names are specified using forward slashes rather than
>   backslashes. If you do use backslashes, you must double them.

Comment: Ok, so how would I give MySQL rights to read from the webroot folder? I am now using `str_replace("\\", "\\\\", WWW_ROOT.'tmp.txt')` in the query, which results in `C:\\Data\\my php application\\app\\webroot\\tmp.txt`.

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html: use the 'secure_file_priv' system variable. However, I would strongly recommend against letting it point to your webapp directory. Rather, set the variable to some temp directory and move your uploaded file there.

Comment: So I should set the `secure_file_priv` variable to `c:\tmp\` or something? I can't figure out how to do that though..

Comment: I think I've got it! I've copied the file my_medium.ini to c:\my.ini and added the line `secure_file_priv='c:/tmp/'`. After a restart the query doesn't give any errors anymore!

Comment: Edit my.cnf, put it in the [mysqld] section, then restart the MySQL server. I can't tell you the location of the configuration file, you will have to find that on your Windows system. I suggest you read the MySQL documentation about Option Files, too.

Comment: Dankje! I guess I'm way too ambitious jumping into these things like that. Just started with CakePHP (heck, just even started with 'structured php').. 'I have no idea what I'm doing`. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

@JvO is guiding you down the right path. I think you're missing a couple of important elements, one of which is moving the uploaded file from its initial temp directory on the server to a place where MySQL can officially read it (it won't read it from a temp directory for security reasons).

Here's an example from a project I did, which uploaded a CSV file and then MOVED it to a readable directory. I first uploaded it with the `move_uploaded_file` function, and then created a variable describing the uploaded path of the new file for use in a LOAD DATA query.

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fCSV"]["tmp_name"],"user_uploads/SG".$dapID ."/". $_FILES["fCSV"]["name"]);`

`$csvfile = "user_uploads/SG".$dapID ."/". $_FILES["fCSV"]["name"];`

In your LOAD DATA query, you're missing the "LOCAL" keyword, which tells MySQL to read the file from a specified directory, otherwise it's looking for it in the database directory (the use of "Field1" etc. below is for demo purposes only and you should have your real table field names in there):

`$sqlLoad = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$csvfile."' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4) SET ID =".$id`

Lastly, you really need to read through this page in the MySQL manual. It covers many of the issues you're dealing with along with providing examples:

[MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)